# web.config file causing 500 internal server error

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am trying to add browser caching to resources on my site. I am completely new to this but found some information on how to do this. It was recommended that I create a web.config file with the following code and place it in my root folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" CacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When I do, however, I get a 500 Internal Server error on my site. Anyone know why this is happening? Is it something to do with permissions? Am I missing something crucial?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It should be in element `system.webServer` instead of `system.web`

Comment: That worked to get around the internal server error, but now all of my images, css (apparently everything but the html) is now returning a 500 Internal Server Error.. ?

Comment: Try add following part of `web.config` for displaying more details about error `<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>`

Comment: It only told me what I found in the response headers "page could not be displayed due to a 500 internal server error"